# Addition of two dates on python 3

Tags: python, csv, datetime, python-3.x

I try adding date and hours from csv file in one datetime variable. I read questions about adding some timedelta and official doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects, but don't understend how it works.

My csv row looks like - ['2005.02.28', '17:38', '1.32690', '1.32720', '1.32680', '1.32720', '5'].I convert row[0] = 2005.02.28 to date and convert row[1] = 17:38. Now i need creating new datetime variable looks like 2005.02.28 17:38. How i can do it?

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
with open('EURUSDM1.csv') as csvfile:
  datereader=csv.reader(csvfile)
      for row in datereader:
          date=dt.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y.%m.%d")
          time=dt.datetime.strptime(row[1], "%H:%M")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have both the values in two variables, `new_date` and `new_time`, you could simply combine them to get the datetime, like this,

```
>>> new_date = dt.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y.%m.%d")
>>> new_time = dt.datetime.strptime(row[1], "%H:%M").time()
>>> 
>>> dt.datetime.combine(new_date, new_time)
datetime.datetime(2005, 2, 28, 17, 38)
```

**Note:-** Avoid using `date` and `time` as variable names, as they are also part of the `datetime` library. Use a variable name that is relevant to your application context.

Answer (score 4):

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
with open('EURUSDM1.csv') as csvfile:
    datereader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in datereader:
        dstr = row[0] + ' ' + row[1]
        date = dt.datetime.strptime(dstr, "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M")
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, it work perfect. But on future, if i have got two object from different files - how i should do addition date and time variable?

Comment: The other answer just posted by @pankaj-parashar answers this.

Comment: Thank you for your decision, it helped me a lot, but I marked an answer pankaj-parashar as a solution to the problem, since it is a more general solution and I think will help others in many cases.

Comment: I completely agree. That one is a much better and elegant solution.